# HTML 5 History - window.pushState not working

Tags: javascript, json, html, jquery, browser-history

I am trying to ajax load the center content and update the URL without changing the page.  This all works fine except until I try to access the history.  It seems window.pushState is not recording my URL's properly or popstate event is not working properly.  I can successfully ajax load the previous page, but if I press back more than once, it stays on the same page.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('area, .ajax_link').live('click', function(event) {
        change_image(this, event);
    });

    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        change_image(window.location, event);
    });
});

function change_image(e, event) {
    if($(e).attr('target') != '_blank') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            base_url+'/kit/ajax_load',
            { url: this_url},
            function(return_data) {
                $('#content img').attr('src', return_data.image_src);
                $('map').html(return_data.imagemap);
            },
            'json'
        );
        history.pushState(null, null, this_url);
        update_links(this_url);
      }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular browser you're seeing this behavior in, or is it the same across all browsers you've tried that support pushState?

Comment: Tested on Chrome and Firefox, same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem Solved**

@Oliver Nightingale: I needed to remove history.pushState from my change_image function.  You can not call history.pushState during an onpopstate.  Here is the entire working code.  I shortened it above only to include the necessary parts in question.  I will be adding some fallbacks next.  This is tested and works in Chrome & Firefox.  Tested and does not work in IE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('area, .ajax_link').live('click', function(event) {
      history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
      change_image(this, event);
  });

  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
      change_image(window.location, event);
  });
});

function change_image(e, event) {
    if(!e instanceof jQuery) {
    var this_url = e;
    }
    else {
        var this_url = $(e).attr('href');
    }

    if($(e).attr('target') != '_blank') {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            base_url+'/kit/ajax_load',
            { url: this_url},
            function(return_data) {
                $('#content img').attr('src', return_data.image_src);
                $('map').html(return_data.imagemap);
            },
            'json'
        );

        update_links(this_url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem (history wasn't working because I was inadvertently calling pushState within a popState). You can now accept your own answer, to make it more prominent on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the main body of change_image function happening onpopstate?  If so it looks like you are pushing a new state everytime you pop a state, this could be causing some issues.

If you are using pushState for routing you could try using a library such as [Davis](http://davisjs.com) to make things simpler.

Comment: Yes, the main body of change_image function is always happening onpopstate.  I have not seen Davis, but I have seen History.js and a Jquery HTML5 History Plugin.  Looks like using a library for this may be the answer but- regardless of the library, I still need to pushState inside of my onpopstate function, right?  How else would that URL be added to the history?

Comment: oops, wont let me paste it here, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

How is `$(e).attr('target') != '_blank'` when `e` is `window.location` ?

As you are using the native HTML5 History API, you'll also want to have a check before `history.pushState(null, null, this_url);` to only call that if we are from a link.

Plus `window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {` the variable `event` here is actually the state's data.

See the following gists for working examples:

- https://gist.github.com/balupton/1145804 - without history.js
- https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify - with history.js