# implementing history in web site not working

Tags: html, browser-history

Here is the flow of events on my web site

1. Go to [http://example.com]. The web page shows the content from http://example.com/foo even though the browser address bar says http://example.com

   The text on the web page asks the user to check out bar. The user clicks on the link and is taken to
2. [http://example.com/bar]

   The text on the web page asks the user to check out baz. The user clicks on the link and is taken to
3. [http://example.com/baz]

   The text on the web page asks the user to check out qux. However, the user clicks on the browser back button and is taken to
4. [http://example.com/bar]

   The text on the web page asks the user to check out baz. However, the user clicks on the browser back button and is taken to ... FAIL! This is where the browser bar should have become [http://example.com] but it doesn't change at all.

The code implementing all this is rather straighforward

```
var goTo: function(uri) {
    get uri via XMLHttpRequest
    swap content
    history.pushState(null, null, uri);
}

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    var uri = location.pathname.replace("\/", "");
    goTo(uri);
}, false);
```

Comment: Your links don't work. `example.com` is a reserved domain - they'll never work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. See [HTML 5 History - window.pushState not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394257/html-5-history-window-pushstate-not-working?rq=1) for details, but the short of it is that I can't have `history.pushState()` inside a `popstate` event. Once I isolated the two, it is working great.